# Confused on SQL Sorting Built In Function for Case Sensitive Searches

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to execute this statement on MYSQL.

`SELECT * FROM mydatabase.mytable where LASTNAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI like '%DOODLEBOP%'`

I keep getting this error: 
`Error Code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AI'`

Any ideas what I am missing or doing wrong? I'm also trying to essentially mimic an article I was reading online. [Case Sensitive Searching](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-sql-server)

I tried a few quick Googles for the error and to no avail. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use Microsoft SQL Server collation name on MySQL server.
For valid MySQL collation names and right syntax refer to MySQL documentation:

- [Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-mysql.html)
- [Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collate.html)

I think closest collation name for you query is: `latin1_general_cs`